# High lock contention and slow performance on ToList() with EF4

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I've got a project that uses EF4 (System.Data.Entities, no nuget package) and hits the context directly for LINQ queries. Whenever I load-test by having multiple users log in (using VS test load testing), I get horrible performance, my CPU shoots to 100%, and VS.NET throws alerts on high .NET lock contention and high garbage collection.

In doing a good deal of profiling and tweaking, everything seems to point to the execution of the LINQ query itself (to be expected to some degree), and an incredible amount of contention on the .ToList() call we make in a bunch of places on the results.

Has anyone experienced this? What's the cause and how do I resolve this? Do I need to thread out the .ToList() call for some reason?

UPDATE:
A few people have asked for more details.. Here is the code in question (tweaked a bit to remove stuff I can't release).

```
var query =
            from f in context.fs
            where f.usr.Any((u) => u.id == id)
            select new
            {
                FS = f,
                f.fList,
                E = from e in f.fList select new { e.er },
                L = from l in f.fList select new { l.id }
            };
    var res = query.ToList();
```

Under heavy load this same code runs on multiple threads (profiler says 13). The ToList() call is absolute murder, and accounts for nearly all the delays.

Comment: Could you provide some more information on the query? How many logins are we talking about?

Comment: Do you have performance profiler? It should tell you exactly which lock causes the problem. It may be completely unrelated to EF itself because for example `Expression` class used heavily for queries can cause lock contention as well. Its processing internally uses lock on static field to control access to some cache.

Comment: Showing the code of the .ToList() calls and how often or where they are being called will be useful.

Comment: Added code as requested!

Comment: Are you talking about 500ms (reading your comment under the answer below)??? If so, I am afraid that this could be "normal". Your query is more complex than eager loading. In your projection you're loading *three collections* together with the parent entity and object materialization (happens with `ToList()`) might be an expensive operation in this case. The projection seems to have redundant parts. Why do you use those two sub-projections when you project the full `fList` anyway? This only costs unnecessary performance both on SQL side and for object materialization.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but LINQ is not my strongest suite.. any suggestions how to improve that statement? The 500ms is the SQL query running in SQL, the ToList on the results takes well over a second.

Comment: @XeroxDucati: See my answer below, maybe it will improve the performance a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your query: If you need the full `fList` entities perform the projection into `E` and `L` *after* the query is executed:

```
var query = from f in context.fs
            where f.usr.Any((u) => u.id == id)
            select new
            {
                FS = f,
                f.fList
            };
var res = query.ToList();
foreach (var x in res)
{
    // runs in memory
    var E = from e in x.fList select new e.er;
    var L = from l in x.fList select new l.id;
    // ...
}
```

If you only need E and L combine them:

```
var query = from f in context.fs
            where f.usr.Any((u) => u.id == id)
            select new
            {
                FS = f,
                EL = from x in f.fList select new { e.er, l.id }
            };
var res = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remember that `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` methods use differed execution.  `IQueryable` methods, in particular, generally do little more than modify expression trees in memory.  From the profiler's point of view they will never take up a noticeable amount of time.  It's not until the `ToList` call that the query (generated from the previous `IQueryable` methods) is actually executed, which means that's where the actual network IO takes place.  The time spent doing that will be *significantly* higher than all of the query generation put together.

In short, the profiler isn't really helping you here.  All of the work is funneled through `ToList`, but the code that determines the efficiency of the query is basically everywhere else.  It's possible that what you want is just inherently an expensive operation, or that you just haven't written the query efficiently (in which case we'd need to know more about it to provide information).

As to whether parallelizing it would help, that's not really know.  My guess is that probably not.  If your CPU is maxed out then you're keeping it busy, and threading would just add more overhead and slow you down.  If the CPU wasn't tasked but it was being slow then it's more likely that threading would be able to help you.

Comment: Makes sense.. but EFprof tells me that the query only takes 500ms to return, and it's not a huge dataset, only a few fields.. Any way to tweak the model or something to improve performance?

Comment: @XeroxDucati You haven't included enough information for us to attempt to answer that.